# How do I access a DOM element with a dynamic ID in Codeception?

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, codeception

I'm new to autotests and I'm just starting to master Codeception. I am writing an autotest and at the end of the autotest I need to delete the . But when creating a new theme, a delete button with a dynamic ID is generated for it. How do I access this button for each new topic? Here is part of the code! The button I need is called "Delete"

```
<span data-theme_id="12445247" class="control_item icon-box_hover empty_link with_icon_link js-deleteTheme">
                                                    <span class="icon-delete-summary mod__hover"></span>Delete</span>
```

Comment: Why not use a class selector? Also, why is this question tagged with PHP and Codeception, but does not contain any code related to it?

Comment: I will try to use class selector. Deleted the PHP tag, thanks for the comment

Comment: Add a tag for the relevant programming language you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see yourself, the `data-theme_id` attribute of this element is dynamically generated for each browsing session. What is seems to be a fixed values are `icon-delete-summary` class name of first `span` element and the `Delete` text of the second `span`.
So, I would guess the following XPath should work here:

```php
"//span[text()='Delete']"
```

Or in case the former locator is not unique maybe this:

```php
"//span[contains(@class,'js-deleteTheme')]//span[contains(.,'Delete')]"
```

Comment: It's works, thanks. But if i use this metods (e.g "//span[text()='Delete']"), all the elements on the page are located. Can you tell me how to tell selenium to select a specific button, Do I need to access through the parent element?

Comment: In case the element itself attributes not making a unique combination - yes, you will have to build the locator based on some parent elements (sometimes not only 1 but several elements) and the desired child element to make a unique locator

Comment: I did it) THanks again! "//td[contains(@class, 'cell_theme_title')][contains(.,'Autotest')]/descendant::span[@class='control_item icon-box_hover empty_link with_icon_link js-deleteTheme']" However, it looks too long)

Comment: I think we could make it shorter, but we have no link to that page to what happens there

Comment: To see this, the user must be logged in, and this is paid resource, so I can't give you a link. Privacy Policy, sorry( I will think for y self how to make it shorter. Thanks

Comment: I understand, no problem, Just tried to help. You should learn how to create effective XPath and CSS Selector locators. It's really simple and very useful for all automation developers

Comment: I will definitely study it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you suggest a resource where I can read about effective Xpath and Css selector locators? I Googled, but I didn't find anything useful

Comment: I'm sorry, but I learned that a long time ago from different sources, so I can't advice about specific tutorial, I'm sorry